# Blender is still running in task manager after I close it and using many system resources

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I was using cycles in the blender viewport, and after I closed it I noticed that my computer was running slowly, when I opened task manager I say multiple instances of blender using almost all of my CPU and memory resources. I have no addons that would provoke this, and in my experience blender does not stay open in the background. Does anybody know what this is? Obviously I can just end the task but I am also worried something is wrong with blender or that maybe it is a computer virus imitating blender.

[image]

Comment: This is extremely unusual. Try launching blender again, and watch what happens in the task manager.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. There are up to 8 processes of blender running in the background.